# I have some very weirdly pieced together materials, can I merge and separate them?

Tags: texturing, materials, objects

I have some very odd Materials in an OBJ file made from photogrammetry. I was wondering, can I combine them all and then separate new objects, materials, and textures?

Comment: Welcome to BSE, adding more details, attaching screen shots, will help getting more accurate answers.

Comment: you can UV unwrap any object and map a texture on it